# Retrieving a list of Dictionaries from Nested Dictionary with an Input from User

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

I'm a bit new to Python and I'm working with Python 3. What I want to do is to retrieve a list of dictionaries, from the nested dictionary, with a similar key to what the user will input.

Here's what I'm doing

```
import pickle
import os
os.system("cls")

p_inputs = {
 'DOE, JOHN': {'SEX': 'MALE', 'AGE': 18},
 'DOE, JANE': {'SEX': 'FEMALE', 'AGE': 18},
 'WEST, MARIA': {'SEX': 'FEMALE', 'AGE': 18}}

print("Please enter the necessary information.")
new_name = input("\nFULL NAME, SURNAME FIRST: ").upper()
new_sex =  input("SEX: ").upper()
new_age = int(input("AGE: "))

p_inputs[new_name] = {'SEX': new_sex, 'AGE': new_age,}
pickle.dump(p_inputs, open("info", "wb"))
```

Now, what should I do when I insert a line where I ask for the user's input, for example, I'm asking for the age. Then the user will type "18", how do I get a list of all the dictionaries of people with the AGE of 18?

I apologize if I got something wrong.

Comment: Where is the list of dictionaries of people supposed to be coming from?

Comment: They're supposed to be entered by the user as well, and I used pickle to save what the user enters. Am I doing it right?

Comment: I edited the post to give a sample of the list of people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to load the existing data like this:

```
with open("info", "rb") as f:
    p_inputs = pickle.load(f)
```

then you can do a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> {k: v for k,v in p_inputs.items() if v["AGE"] == 18}
{'name2': {'SEX': 'sex1', 'AGE': 18}, 'name3': {'SEX': 'sex2', 'AGE': 18}}
```

Btw: Currently you override evertime the dict and store only the newest person.

---

**Edit:** Full solution

```
import os
import pickle

os.system("cls")

try:
    with open("info", "rb") as f:
        p_inputs = pickle.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
    p_inputs = {}

print("Please enter the necessary information.")
new_name = input("\nFULL NAME, SURNAME FIRST: ").upper()
new_sex = input("SEX: ").upper()
new_age = int(input("AGE: "))

p_inputs[new_name] = {'SEX': new_sex, 'AGE': new_age}
with open("info", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(p_inputs, f)

print("Added")
print()

search_age = int(input("Show people with this age: "))
search_result = {k: v for k, v in p_inputs.items() if v["AGE"] == search_age}
print(search_result)
```

Input/Output

```
Please enter the necessary information.

FULL NAME, SURNAME FIRST: DOE, JOHN
SEX: MALE
AGE: 18
Added

Show people with this age: 18
{'DOE, JANE': {'SEX': 'FEMALE', 'AGE': 18}, 'DOE, JOHN': {'SEX': 'MALE', 'AGE': 18}, 'WEST, MARIA': {'SEX': 'FEMALE', 'AGE'
: 18}}
```

Comment: That clarified a lot in my problem, thanks. But what if, I wanted to print the dicts with the same AGE, without having to put it in the syntax, like you did?

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to use the age of the new person or an extra question. I've edited my question and added an example of how to use this dynamically/interactively.

Comment: Thanks! I got it, sorry about the confusion. That's exactly what I wanted to do.